# google play services debug key

Tags: android, debugging, key

Hello I have a strange and stupid problem. 
1. I added debug key (which I've taken from eclipse>android>build)
2. I uninstalled application and run in debug mode.

I have "the app is incorectly configured error" all the time. I made it working once but can't do it again. Do you know why?

Comment: share the full error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone who will eventually face the problem. This is what helped me:
First of all i did everything correctly and checked it many times with official google play "possible problems" guide and some unofficial guides on stackoverflow etc.
To make it work I've uninstalled the game, cleaned RAM, restarted telephone and run in debug mode (i think it doesn't matter you run it in debug or normal, it's always signed with the same key).
I've also waited about 0,5h until I've checked. It worked.
Few moments ago I've tried the same at work (different debug key). Did everything but restarting phone. It worked too.

Conclusion:
Either some information are stored in RAM and you have to clean it or you just have to wait until your setup in dev console will be seen to the device. Maybe both.